# modifying url shortner script

Tags: php, mysql, short-url

I've been using [Johnboy URL shortner](http://johnboy.me/index.php?code=1) and I noticed it doesn't check and see if the URL that it generates exists in the database.  How could I ensure that the URL is unique>

Comment: You could check for the URL in the database before the `INSERT` query. I'd use a better script, though, considering that it doesn't even check if the shortened URL is already in-use either.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Isn't that what this question is about?

Comment: Make sure you modify the script to prevent XSS: http://johnboy.me/?s=%22%3E%3C/a%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/enhanced-buzz-2782-1301948354-46-1.jpeg?w=500&h=500%22%20/%3E%3C/h2%3E%3C!--

Comment: Actually, it does check if the URL is already shortened. I'm talking about the shortened URL, BTW - like the random 5 char string.

Comment: @Tomalak With no indication of what he's tried or his technical knowledge, it's hard to say.

Comment: @ceejayoz: No it's not. It's what he's asking about. That's what the question says!

Comment: He asked how to ensure the URL is unique. "Check in the database first" is a perfectly valid answer. If he wants code, he should a) say so and b) consider paying someone to do his work for him.

Comment: @ceejayoz: He was talking about "the URL that it generates". i.e. the shortened URL. Your suggestion is indeed perfectly valid, but then you went on to bring up -- almost as a different point -- the original question again! ("either")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding `UNIQUE` to the database column `url_link` should do.

Comment: $short = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 5);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO urls (url_link, url_short, url_ip, url_date) VALUES

 (
 '".addslashes($_POST['url'])."',
 '".$short."',
 '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
 '".time()."'
 )

");

where do i put it?

Comment: Add `, UNIQUE KEY (\`url_link\`)` after the `PRIMARY KEY  (\`url_id\`)` in `db.php`.

Comment: Since I did that, if the key exists what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [unique index/constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for the long or the short url or both. When the script tries to insert another record with the same values the INSERT statement will fail with a [specific error code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry) which you can test for and handle appropriately.

```
define('MYSQL_ER_DUP_ENTRY', 1062);
...
if ( !mysql_query($mysql, $query) ) {
  if ( MYSQL_ER_DUP_ENTRY==mysql_errno($mysql) ) {
    // handle duplicate entry
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like johnboy's script is full of vulnerabilities...but here ya go! (modified index.php script where it calculates the new short url)

```
$short = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 5); 
$unique = false;
while(!$unique) {
    $exists = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = '".$short."'")); 
    if($exists['url_link'] != '') {
        // one already exists! create another, try again.
        $short = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 5); 
    } else {
        $unique = true;
    }
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO urls (url_link, url_short, url_ip, url_date) VALUES 
    ( 
    '".addslashes($_POST['url'])."', 
    '".$short."', 
    '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', 
    '".time()."' 
    ) 
");
```

Comment: You'd have to lock the table to avoid race conditions, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing

Answer (score 2):

The DB table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `urls` (
  `url_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `url_link` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `url_short` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `url_date` int(10) default NULL,
  `url_ip` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `url_hits` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`url_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The primary key is a auto-incremented integer that is not used anywhere across the app. You can just get rid of it and use `url_short` as primary key. You can then do one of three things when inserting new stuff:

1. Use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and discard dupes silently.
2. Use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and update dupes.
3. Use regular `INSERT` and check the error code: if 1062, it's a dupe.

I'd go for #3.

However, considering that it uses `addslashes()` to inject input parameters into SQL I'd just avoid using this script at all. It looks way obsolete and insecure.

Answer (score 0):

you could use foreign key constraints to ensure unique urls at the database level. Then, in the php, check that the query inserted a row - if so, then you know a unique url has been inserted, if not, then give the user or script a chance to try it again with a new string.